# docs.google.com behind browser proxy does not work

Tags: proxy, google-docs

Some of our clients use ezproxy to restrict internet access for their users.

Ezproxy changes the domain name in the browser.

So docs.google.com could become docs.google.com.myezproxy.com.

In this case, the document opened just keeps saying "Loading... something went wrong, retrying..."

I did some investigation and found that some js files return 403 forbidden.

On further investigation, found that Google returns 403 because the referer domain is not docs.google.com. I confirmed this with curl calls. If the domain is docs.google.com it works, else returns 403.

Is there any way to fix it.

Comment: can you clarify what you want to achieve. Your question is tagged google-drive-sdk, which works just fine through a proxy (provided the access token is being forwarded in the request).

Comment: Exactly what Rivero has mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the Google Drive web app (accessing by drive.google.com) does not support access through proxies. You can read about the settings for firewalls and proxies, and try [these configurations](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2589954?hl=en) to enable access. But so far, granting access is still listed as a feature request, as seen [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=265792).

Comment: helpful links. could you rephrase your answer to explain what you mean by "Drive". For example, the Drive SDK *does* support proxies, so you're referring to some other aspect, the Drive web application at http://drive.google.com perhaps?

Comment: Apologies, I am referring to Drive as a web app (accessing through the link drive.google.com)